# In Async task in doinbackground methode i am getting null return value of feeditem

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-asynctask

In the an async task in the `doinbackground` method I am getting a `null` return  value for `List` of `FeedItems`.

Below is my `asynctask` class code. How do I return a `List` of `FeedItems`? I have  added items to `List<FeedItem>` inside the for loop. How do I return the value of List from inside the for loop (or any other way)?

```
private class AsynFetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, FeedItem, List<FeedItem>> {
        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected List<FeedItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {


            ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("NewsAndUpdates");
            parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(final List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if (e==null){
                        List<FeedItem> feedItems= new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            final FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                            item.setTitle(list.get(i).getString("Title"));
                            item.setDescription(list.get(i).getString("Description"));
                            item.setTime(list.get(i).getDate("createdAt"));
                            ParseFile file = list.get(i).getParseFile("File");
                            file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                               public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                   if (e==null){
                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                        item.setThumbnail(bmp);
                                       publishProgress(item);
                                   }else {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.No_Internet,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }


                                }
                            });
                            if (item != null) {
                                feedItems.add(item);
                            }

                        }

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.No_Internet,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(FeedItem... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<FeedItem> feedItems) {

            super.onPostExecute(feedItems);
            adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,feedItems);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning null in your doInBackground, return feedItems like this:

```
private class AsynFetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, FeedItem, List<FeedItem>> {
        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected List<FeedItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {


            ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("NewsAndUpdates");
            parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(final List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if (e==null){
                        List<FeedItem> feedItems= new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            final FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                            item.setTitle(list.get(i).getString("Title"));
                            item.setDescription(list.get(i).getString("Description"));
                            item.setTime(list.get(i).getDate("createdAt"));
                            ParseFile file = list.get(i).getParseFile("File");
                            file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                               public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                   if (e==null){
                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                        item.setThumbnail(bmp);
                                       publishProgress(item);
                                   }else {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.No_Internet,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }


                                }
                            });
                            if (item != null) {
                                feedItems.add(item);
                            }

                        }

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.No_Internet,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });


            return feedItems;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(FeedItem... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<FeedItem> feedItems) {

            super.onPostExecute(feedItems);
            adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,feedItems);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        }
    }
```

Comment: now returning feeditems but it is empty ,items that are added in for loop that are not adding

Comment: check feedItems for items whether items are added or not.

Comment: if I execute Log.d("description",feeditem.get(0).getDescription()) inside for loop then I am getting my output which is  at position 0,but if I execute this outside for loop I am getting null.

Comment: what do you get in log?

Comment: I am getting my expected String output when I execute inside my for loop  above log code ,and when I try this log code outside loop i dose not get any output

Comment: if (feedItems.isEmpty()){
    Log.d("amar","empty");
} i executed this outside then i am getting this in log     D/amar: empty

Comment: do this if (item != null) {
                                feedItems.add(item);
                            }  inside your done callback